# A way to convert an XML string to a JavaScript object without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, xml, object

Does anybody know how to convert a valid XML string into a JavaScript object **without** using jQuery or other DOM libraries?

The reason I'd like to do it just in JavaScript is because this is all server-side and doesn't have anything to do with a particular browser.

Just to re-emphasize - **this is not client-side JavaScript**. It is server-side.

Thanks,

doug

Comment: could you show some relevant code, may be the XML you want to convert to JS object..

Comment: What server side environment are you using? Rhino? Node.js. The answer will be different depending on your interpreter (just like in web browsers eh?)

Comment: Javascript is client-side. I would highly suggest using JSON instead, but here is some reference for you: http://w3schools.com/xml/xml_to_html.asp

Comment: I'm using Webcrossing. Perhaps not as well known. The server-side JS is an enhanced version of SpiderMonkey. Right now there is no relevant code to show. I'm simply fetching XML from another site. That's just one line. Now I would like to find some way to parse it.

Comment: Please note that JavaScript is not only client-side. That's its most common usage, but there are also server-side JavaScripts. I'm using one that works with the Webcrossing object-oriented database. Converting to JSON would probably also be ok because I can go from there to an object using eval.

Comment: Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/8cXg3/

Comment: John, that link appears to be a client-side solution of some kind.

Comment: Why do you not want to use a DOM library?

Comment: Perhaps I'm being dumb here, but don't DOM libraries just work on the client-side document?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect John Paul Cardenas' snippet in the comments is the closest you're going to get. Hopefully you can find a DOM library in your particular server-side environment, I'm not familiar with the platform you've described.

Assuming you can find something similar to DOMParser (see http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp for a little more info on XML parsing in JS), that's the best way I know of to get started.

Of course from there, you'll be parsing the code manually by traversing the DOM tree. That's because there's no standard way to convert XML to JSON; they're not exactly directly compatible. For instance, XML nodes have attributes; JSON does not. How you handle the nuances depends on your particular XML schema, and the needs of your particular project.

Answer (score 0):

I tried looking at Webcrossing but it appears that they don't have online documentation for the product. I guess you have to pay to get the documentation which is a bit of a surprise because even commercial products these days tend to have free online docs - how else would a developer evaluate the product?

If you do have access to the documentation (which you should since you/your employer paid for it) I suggest looking up how to handle XML in the docs. Webcrossing claims to have built in XMLRPC capabilities which should imply built-in XML parsing capabilities.

Most javascript engines that have such things built in tend to implement a DOM parser which converts the XML into a DOM object. The advantage of this is you can use the familiar DOM operations such as `getElementById()`, `getElementsByTagName()`, `element.children` etc to traverse and process the XML document. The disadvantage of this is you need to use the verbose DOM operations above to traverse and process the XML document.

However, if Webcrossing doesn't provide a built in XML parser (which is unlikely since it supports XMLRPC) your next best bet is to port over a node.js module. Some XML related modules are listed here:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-parsers-xml

The list above is not exhaustive. For a full list you can search the npm registry here:

https://npmjs.org/

From a quick search on google it looks to me that your best bet would be to port this module (which is incidentally not listed in the wiki):

https://github.com/nfarina/xmldoc

The xmldoc module is unique in that is was designed to work in node as well as web browsers. So it probably has a better chance of being ported.

In any case, read through your documentation first (or contact Webcrossing's tech support).

Comment: First a disclaimer - I am involved with Webcrossing. I have used it for a long time and am a principle in the organization. So I just wanted to be clear about that. That said, the documentation is online at http://faq.elliptics.com/FAQ/Docs/. As you pointed out, Webcrossing can act as both an XML-RPC client and server. It's actually quite easy and cool to use for that. You can make and receive calls without actually having to create or look at XML at all. It's completely transparent. Anyway, I'm looking to see what's available in the server. There is apparently an xmlToObject method.